# VS Code: How to split horizontally with one vertical split

Tags: visual-studio-code

Basic question: I have this layout in VS Code:

```
A | B
```

A and B contain multiple files. Now I want this:

```
A | B
-----
  C
```

Somehow I am unable to get this layout without manually moving all files around till there is no vertical split anymore. From this point on, I can get to my target layout. Is there a quicker method? Basically, I can only get to these layouts if I try to snap one file to a new location, which is not what I want:

```
A | B       A | B
--|           |--
C |           | C
```

Answer (score 1):

There is pre-configured layout for your case:
*View -> Editor Layout -> Two Columns Botto*m

For quick access you can create keybinding:
*File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*
Search for "Two Columns Bottom Editor Layout"

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your `A | B`:

then focus A or B and in the Command Palette trigger the command:

`View: New Editor Group Below`  and you will be at

```
A | B       A | B
--|           |--
C |           | C
```

depending on whether A or B was focused.

The commands could be combined into a macro keybindings:

```
{
  "key": "alt+w",                         // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.newGroupLeft",   // or newGroupRight
      "workbench.action.newGroupBelow"
    ]
  },
}
```

Using the `Multi Command` extension.  Start with a single editor group.